# How to get isolated vertices on a graph

Tags: graph-algorithm, arangodb, vertices

How do I get the isolated vertices on a graph. I'm new to arangodb.
I want to get all the isolated vertices and delete them to make it easier for me to analyze the data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [retrieve vertices with no linked edge in arangodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36271753/retrieve-vertices-with-no-linked-edge-in-arangodb)

Answer (score 2):

Using ArangoDB 3.x, the following AQL query will count the isolated nodes in `@nodes` relative to a specific edge collection, `@edges`:

```
FOR v IN @nodes
 LET degree = (FOR v1 IN 1..1 ANY v @edges 
               COLLECT WITH COUNT INTO c RETURN c)[0]
 FILTER degree==0
 COLLECT WITH COUNT into c
 RETURN c
```

If there is possibly more than one relevant Edge collection, you will have to specify them all explicitly unless you want to rely on the existing specifications in a named graph.  In that case, you would replace `@edges` above with `GRAPH mygraph`, where mygraph is the name of the relevant named graph.

Once you've verified this is what you want, you can then modify the above to delete the vertices.

The above method (based on counting edges) is rather resource-intensive, but I don't know a better alternative, as even in JavaScript, you would probably have to use inEdges() and outEdges().  Possibly vertex-centric indices might help.

For an edge-first approach, see [retrieve vertices with no linked edge in arangodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36271753/retrieve-vertices-with-no-linked-edge-in-arangodb)